# Altair plot doesn't show up using column name parameters in the Python def

Tags: python, function, parameters, altair

This Python def feeds in a column name but the Altair code doesn't appear to use it

```
def gapsindata( name_of_column ):
    print(outer_join_df )
    
    
     
    print("'" + name_of_column  + ":O'")
    print("'" + name_of_column  + ":N'")
    
    bars =  alt.Chart(outer_join_df).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.Y('PercentMissing:Q'),
    x= "'" + name_of_column  + ":O'",
    color= "'" + name_of_column  + ":N'",
    )

    text = bars.mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
    dx=1  # Nudges text to right so it doesn't appear on top of the bar
    ).encode(
    text='PercentMissing:Q'
    )

    (bars + text).properties(height=200).facet(column= "'" + name_of_column  + ":N'")
 
    
    return;


gapsindata('DfService')
```

While using the column names fed in through a Python def parameter, I can't get the Altair plot to show up. This is the output:

```
Outer Join DF
   DfService|       FieldName  |MissingItemCnt  |ItemCnt  |PercentMissing
0         No|    Model Number  |             0  |     53  |      0.000000
1         No|        SKU type  |             8  |     53  |     15.094340
2         No|  Equipment Type  |             1  |     53  |      1.886792
3        Yes|    Model Number  |             0  |    204  |      0.000000
4        Yes|        SKU type  |            52  |    204  |     25.490196
5        Yes|  Equipment Type  |             1  |    204  |      0.490196
'DfService:O'
'DfService:N'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is returning `None`, so your notebook is displaying `None` after your function call.

It's similar to this function:

```python
def f(x):
  2 * x
  return None
```

You will not see the `2 * x` result when calling the function, because the function is not doing anything with it.

If you want the chart to be displayed, a good approach is to return the chart:

```python
def gapsindata( name_of_column ):
    ...

    return (bars + text).properties(height=200).facet(column= "'" + name_of_column  + ":N'")

gapsindata('DfService')
```